# Extracting everything between two symbols in a string

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a vector containing some names. I want to extract the title on every row, basically everything between the ", " (included the white space) and "."

```
> head(combi$Name)
[1] "Braund, Mr. Owen Harris"
[2] "Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)"
[3] "Heikkinen, Miss. Laina"
[4] "Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)"
[5] "Allen, Mr. William Henry"
[6] "Moran, Mr. James"
```

I suppose `gsub` might come useful but I have difficulties on find the right regular expressions to accomplish my needs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1) sub** With `sub`

```
> sub(".*, ([^.]*)\\..*", "\\1", Name)
[1] "Mr"   "Mrs"  "Miss" "Mrs"  "Mr"   "Mr"
```

**1a) sub variation** This approach with `gsub` also works:

```
> sub(".*, |\\..*", "", Name)
[1] "Mr"   "Mrs"  "Miss" "Mrs"  "Mr"   "Mr"
```

**2) strapplyc** or using `strapplyc` in the gusbfn package it can be done with a simpler regular expression:

```
> library(gsubfn)
>
> strapplyc(Name, ", ([^.]*)\\.", simplify = TRUE)
[1] "Mr"   "Mrs"  "Miss" "Mrs"  "Mr"   "Mr"
```

**2a) strapplyc variation**  This one seems to have the simplest regular expression of them all.

```
> library(gsubfn)
>
> sapply(strapplyc(Name, "\\w+"), "[", 2)
[1] "Mr"   "Mrs"  "Miss" "Mrs"  "Mr"   "Mr"
```

**3) strsplit** A third way is using `strsplit`

```
> sapply(strsplit(Name, ", |\\."), "[", 2)
[1] "Mr"   "Mrs"  "Miss" "Mrs"  "Mr"   "Mr"
```

*Added* additional solutions.  Changed `gsub` to `sub` (although `gsub` works too).

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. I need to study a bit regular expressions.

Comment: I found a case in which the results is wrong: `"Rothschild, Mrs. Martin (Elizabeth L. Barrett)"`. Using the `gsub` command the result is: `" Mrs. Martin (Elizabeth L"`. Thank you in advance

Comment: ok. Have modified 1 and 2 to handle that. 1a and 3 already handled that.

Answer (score 2):

Not to note that there's anything lacking from G. Grothendieck's answer. I just want to add a solution using `sub` and non-greedy repetition:

```
vec <- c("Moran, Mr. James",
         "Rothschild, Mrs. Martin (Elizabeth L. Barrett)")

sub(".*, (.+?)\\..*", "\\1", vec)
# [1] "Mr"  "Mrs"
```

Another alternative with `regexpr`, `regmatches`, and lookbehind/lookahead:

```
regmatches(vec, regexpr("(?<=, ).+?(?=\\.)", vec, perl = TRUE))
# [1] "Mr"  "Mrs"
```